# Python - code type flags

Tags: python

I was looking at the codetype object, and in particular the co_flags attribute.

I wrote a tiny function

```
def f(a,b,c,*args):
   print a,b,c,args
```

Which was compiled to a codetype object. examining the codetype object, the container (the outer codetype) co_flag is set to 64, the function (the inner codetype) is 71

According to the docs 0x40 (64) is set if the function has variable args (eg *args) and that bit is set on the outer and inner codetype objects.

I'm just wondering

- why the container is set to 64 as all it does is set functions up eg there is no variable arguments used?
- what the other bits in the function codetype co_flags do?

Is there a comprehensive list of the various flags as the documentation alludes to 'reserved for internal use' but nothing else is mentioned?

I'm using python 2.7.10

Comment: It's not clear how you're getting two code objects here. What do you mean by "container"? Could you provide the expressions you used to access these two code objects?

Comment: And what docs are you reading? As far as I'm aware, 0x4 is the varargs flag, not 0x40.

Comment: @user2357112 official docs and using the compile command the code is encloses in triple "

Comment: Can you link the docs you're reading?

Comment: @user2357112 not from my current device, but will do tomorrow, you are you right it is 0x4 - my bad

Answer (score 6):

> what the other bits in the function codetype co_flags do?

From `dis.COMPILER_FLAG_NAMES`:

```
  1 OPTIMIZED
  2 NEWLOCALS
  4 VARARGS
  8 VARKEYWORDS
 16 NESTED
 32 GENERATOR
 64 NOFREE
128 COROUTINE
256 ITERABLE_COROUTINE
```

It is from Python 3 but flags that are available in Python 2.7 have kept the same values from [Include/code.h](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Include/code.h#l32). They are documented only by [Jython](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/CodeFlag.html).

> the function (the inner codetype) is 71

`71 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 64`:

```
  1 OPTIMIZED
  2 NEWLOCALS
  4 VARARGS
 64 NOFREE
```

Example (in Python 3):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(a, b, c, *args):
...     print(a, b, c, args)
... 
>>> dis.show_code(f)
Name:              f
Filename:          <stdin>
Argument count:    3
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  4
Stack size:        5
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, VARARGS, NOFREE
Constants:
   0: None
Names:
   0: print
Variable names:
   0: a
   1: b
   2: c
   3: args
```

> why the container is set to 64 as all it does is set functions up eg there is no variable arguments used?

As I understand "the container" is a module (check `co_name`). `NOFREE` just means that there are no `freevars`, `cellvars` that is (always?) true for a module. On `pypy` `co_flags` is `0` ([the flags are the same there](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/56f608d8072c463c1d54efebb9f7299853a0b36c/pypy/interpreter/astcompiler/consts.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)).