# What is flags in Python?

Tags: python

I was playing with interactive shell, testing new stuff etc. I found a function has three flags.

```
def bar(x,y):
    pass

>>> dis.show_code(bar)
Name:              bar
Filename:          test.py
Argument count:    2
Positional-only arguments: 0
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  2
Stack size:        1
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, NOFREE
Constants:
   0: None
Variable names:
   0: x
   1: y
```

Also a string has 1 flag

```
string = "s"

>>> dis.show_code(string)
Filename:          <disassembly>
Flags:             NOFREE
```

The question is why we have them or why do we need them?

Comment: ``dis.show_code(string)`` is not the flags of the string object. Its the flags of the *code object derived from compiling this string as source code*. ``dis.show_code`` will ["Print detailed code object information for the supplied function, method, **source code string** or code object (...)"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.show_code). Compare ``dis.show_code("for for s")``. What makes you think ``dis`` could disassemble types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - code type flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683217/python-code-type-flags)

Comment: Thanks for explanation @MisterMiyagi you are right, but everything is an object, which means every entity has some metadata called attributes and associated functionality, that made me think i can disassemble types.

Comment: You cannot disassemble types. As the documentation states, `dis.show_code()` does "Print detailed code object information for the supplied function, method, source code string or code object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) says:

> The following flag bits are defined for co_flags: bit `0x04` is set if
> the function uses the `*arguments` syntax to accept an arbitrary number
> of positional arguments; bit `0x08` is set if the function uses the
> `**keywords` syntax to accept arbitrary keyword arguments; bit `0x20` is set if the function is a generator.
>
> Future feature declarations (`from __future__ import division`) also use
> bits in `co_flags` to indicate whether a code object was compiled with a
> particular feature enabled: bit `0x2000` is set if the function was
> compiled with future division enabled; bits `0x10` and `0x1000` were used
> in earlier versions of Python.
>
> Other bits in `co_flags` are reserved for internal use.

In the Python source code, you can find this more extensive list of flags in [`code.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b8f704d2190125a7750b50cd9b67267b9c20fd43/Include/cpython/code.h#L67):

```
#define CO_OPTIMIZED    0x0001
#define CO_NEWLOCALS    0x0002
#define CO_VARARGS      0x0004
#define CO_VARKEYWORDS  0x0008
#define CO_NESTED       0x0010
#define CO_GENERATOR    0x0020
#define CO_NOFREE       0x0040
#define CO_COROUTINE            0x0080
#define CO_ITERABLE_COROUTINE   0x0100
#define CO_ASYNC_GENERATOR      0x0200
#define CO_FUTURE_DIVISION      0x20000
#define CO_FUTURE_ABSOLUTE_IMPORT 0x40000
#define CO_FUTURE_WITH_STATEMENT  0x80000
#define CO_FUTURE_PRINT_FUNCTION  0x100000
#define CO_FUTURE_UNICODE_LITERALS 0x200000
#define CO_FUTURE_BARRY_AS_BDFL  0x400000
#define CO_FUTURE_GENERATOR_STOP  0x800000
#define CO_FUTURE_ANNOTATIONS    0x1000000
```

Comment: `CO_FUTURE_BARRY_AS_BDFL` is my favourite. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007289/so-what-exactly-does-from-future-import-barry-as-flufl-do

Answer (score 3):

These `FLAGS` signify different components of a `code` object. While the other answer points you towards the right answer, I am just adding a little fun to the mix.

You can try importing a subset of `FLAGS` from `dis`.

```
>>> from dis import COMPILER_FLAG_NAMES
>>> COMPILER_FLAG_NAMES
{1: 'OPTIMIZED',
 2: 'NEWLOCALS',
 4: 'VARARGS',
 8: 'VARKEYWORDS',
 16: 'NESTED',
 32: 'GENERATOR',
 64: 'NOFREE',
 128: 'COROUTINE',
 256: 'ITERABLE_COROUTINE',
 512: 'ASYNC_GENERATOR'}
```

And then you can write a simple function and see what `FLAGS` show up:

```
>>> def foo():
        return

>>> dis.show_code(foo)
Name:              foo
Filename:          <ipython-input-138-32384d979b8a>
Argument count:    0
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  0
Stack size:        1
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, NOFREE
Constants:
   0: None
```

Now, you can start increasing the complexity and see how that changes:

```
>>> def foo(a, *args, **kwargs):
        yield a
>>> dis.show_code(foo)
Name:              foo
Filename:          <ipython-input-141-56a68ddd064c>
Argument count:    1
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  3
Stack size:        1
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, VARARGS, VARKEYWORDS, GENERATOR, NOFREE
Constants:
   0: None
Variable names:
   0: a
   1: args
   2: kwargs
```

Here adding `*args`, `**kwargs` and `yield` added `VARARGS, VARKEYWORDS, GENERATOR` flags respectively.
Now for something a little more:

```
>>> from asyncio import coroutine
>>> @coroutine
    async def foo(a, *args, **kwargs):
        yield b
        def bar():
            return foo(b)
        yield bar
>>> dis.show_code(foo)
Name:              coro
Filename:          C:\Users\sayan\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\asyncio\coroutines.py
Argument count:    0
Kw-only arguments: 0
Number of locals:  4
Stack size:        8
Flags:             OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, VARARGS, VARKEYWORDS, NESTED, GENERATOR, ITERABLE_COROUTINE
Constants:
   0: None
Names:
   0: base_futures
   1: isfuture
   2: inspect
   3: isgenerator
   4: isinstance
   5: CoroWrapper
   6: __await__
   7: AttributeError
   8: collections
   9: abc
  10: Awaitable
Variable names:
   0: args
   1: kw
   2: res
   3: await_meth
Free variables:
   0: func
```

And there you go, adding `@coroutine` decorator gives `NESTED`, `async_def + yield` gives `ITERABLE_COROUTINE` and the presence of a freevar, that is the function `bar` here, removes the `NOFREE` flag.